# Constrained CRF vs ABR with VBV-constrained bitrate for VoD

Tags: ffmpeg, streaming, encoding

In [this](https://slhck.info/video/2017/03/01/rate-control.html) post [slhck](https://superuser.com/users/48078/slhck) mentions that for VoD (not to be confused with live streaming) one should use one of the two methods for compression:

- Capped CRF
- ABR with VBV-constrained bitrate

I feel pretty confident in understanding how these methods differ, but I do not really understand if one is *better* than the other and if so why.

In my head, it makes the most sense to use a Capped CRF with `-maxrate` (constrained mode). The encoder will then calculate the best bitrate for me, and if that bitrate is higher than, say my upload speed, the encoder will limit the bitrate. Because of this it makes no sense to use a fixed bitrate like setting `-b:v 5000K` unless it is super important to maintain a certain bitrate at all times. But why would it?

Am I wrong in my assumption here?

Should I go for a Capped CRF with `-maxrate` or is there a downside I am not seeing?

Comment: Actually there is no two pass CRF. It's inherently one-pass. You mean constrained/capped CRF?

Comment: Yes, that is of course what I meant. Sorry I was tired last night.

Comment: You're talking about upload speed. But your use case is VoD, right? If you don't care about bitrate too much, CRF should be fine. I can post a more detailed answer later, of course.

Comment: Yeah in this particular case I was thinking about services like Jellyfin, Emby, Plex and so on where upload speed matters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a hard limit on upload speeds, but otherwise do not care about file size, then capped CRF encoding seems like the best compromise. It'll save file size for clips that are easy to encode, but will also enforce a maximum rate for parts that are harder to encode.

So, you could do:

```
ffmpeg -i <input> -c:v libx264 -crf 23 -maxrate 2M -bufsize 4M <output>
```

The CRF parameter and maximum rate/bufsize depends on the resolution and type of content. Full HD clips will require a much larger bitrate (above 8 MBit/s for H.264), and for 4K, I recommend you switch to H.265, since the bitrate for H.264 would be too extreme. Since this is VoD, you probably have more time for encoding anyway, so you can afford the slower H.265 encoder.

Generally, if your CRF is set too low, you will always be hitting the cap; and vice-versa. You should ideally do some experiments and see what the bitrate looks like when you do a non-capped encode with a chosen CRF value. For Windows, [Bitrate Viewer](https://www.videohelp.com/software/Bitrate-Viewer-2) is a useful tool. For Linux, [`plotbitrate`](https://github.com/zeroepoch/plotbitrate) seems useful (but I haven't tried it yet).

Comment: Thanks for elaborating on this, this makes sense. Now the only thing I feel worried about is how to know which buffer size to go for, but that is another question. As per your example, I just keep it 2 times the maxrate.

Comment: I think that'd be a reasonable default.

Comment: When I check the video in Bitrate Viewer I can see that the peak bit rate goes far beyond the maximum bit rate I set in the command. Is this normal?

Comment: It would be good to show an example and, ideally, upload a sample file to test with.

Comment: Here is an example: https://i.imgur.com/5O2KkzD.png The settings used was `-c:v libx264 -crf 20 -maxrate 8M -bufsize 16M`.

Comment: Here is the original: https://i.imgur.com/K7PHewt.png

Comment: The peak is 20% higher than the maxrate you specified. I think it comes down to the definition of bitrate. Sure, the instantaneous bitrate may have large peaks, if, for instance, you only look at every 1 second of video. But if you increase that window to, say, 5 seconds, that effect will probably not be noticeable. That said, the input file looks like it's almost been forced to use a certain bitrate even though it wasn't necessary.